# PUSH toast notification not showing when App is open

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am sending a notification from my server to the app, but the App only receives the notification when it is close. I know there is a line that you have to add so that your app will receive the notification while it is open and I have that in my code. (SEE BELOW) I am using this same code across 2 apps, with the same result.

```
        public App()
                {

                    string channelName = "PushChannel";
                    pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);
                    //Push Notifications
                    if (pushChannel == null)
                    {
                        pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

                        //// Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
                        pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                        pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

                        // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
                        pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

                        pushChannel.Open();

                        // Bind this new channel for toast events.
                        pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
                        pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                        pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

                        // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
                        pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

                        // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.enter code here
                        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            pushURI = pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString();
                        });
                    }
              }



     void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
            {
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    pushURI = e.ChannelUri.ToString();
                });
            }


void PushChannel_ErrorOccurred(object sender, NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            // Error handling logic for your particular application would be here.
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("A push notification {0} error occurred.  {1} ({2}) {3}",
                    e.ErrorType, e.Message, e.ErrorCode, e.ErrorAdditionalData));
            });
        }

void PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            string relativeUri = string.Empty;

            // Parse out the information that was part of the message.
            foreach (string key in e.Collection.Keys)
            {
                if (string.Compare(
                    key,
                    "wp:Param",
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    relativeUri = e.Collection[key];
                }
            }
        }
```

Any information would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In windows phone apps you have to say that it can receive toast notifications, in Visual Studio open your project-> select package.appxmanifest and in the Application tab you have this: http://i.imgur.com/A1XDpbQ.png

Comment: question answered at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600458/push-not-showing-when-app-is-open